# Accessing class variable within class_eval fails

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain the following behavior:

```
class X
  @@x  = 1
end

X.class_eval { @@x } #=> NameError: uninitialized class variable ...
X.class_eval { class_variable_get :@@x } #=> 1
```

Tested in MRI 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 with the same results. Why can't I directly use `@@x` from inside of the `X.class_eval { ... }` block here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens class variable access is lexically scoped. Ruby actually gives you a warning when you run your code that hints at this:

> warning: class variable access from toplevel

Which indicates that the class variable is being resolved in the top-level scope. We can show this is true by assigning inside the `class_eval` and then accessing it outside:

```
X.class_eval { @@x = 42 }
@@x  #=> 42
```

This proves the lexical nature of class variables which causes `class_eval` (which mutates `self`) to have no effect.<sup>†</sup>

Unfortunately I can’t find a good reference documenting this behavior, though some other specifics about class variable assignment is covered in [*Programming Ruby*’s section “Scope of Constants and Variables”](http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UP).

<sup><sup>†</sup> Note that `X.class_variable_get(:@@x)` will also be `42` because `X`’s `@@x` is inherited from the top-level. We can see this by making a new class without an explicit `@@x`: `Class.new.class_variable_get(:@@x) #=> 42`.</sup>

Comment: And this is just one of the *many* examples why you should actually *read* the warnings. Someone put in the effort to code those warnings to help you spot mistakes. Not reading them is kinda rude!

Comment: @JörgWMittag, why do you think I didn't *read* the warnings? I decided to not include them in the question, that could be a mistake, but that's another story, isn't it?